# How to integrate worldpay gateway in android?

Tags: android, worldpay

I have searched in google but I could not get solution.Please help me how to integrate worldpay gateway in android?. Thanks for giving solution in advance.

Answer (score 3):

"The documentation can be found at http://rbsworldpay.com/support/bg/index.php?page=guides&c=UK

Sounds like you need the 'Payment Notifications' guide,

The Payment Response is an HTTP POST and is sent when a payment is Authorised or the user clicks 'Cancel' on the payment page.

You can find the set of data sent in this under 'Reference', 'Payment Message', 'Parameter Descriptions' in the Payment Notifications guide on the above page."

Comment: he is asking how to integrate an android app with worldpay from scratch. just like we do in paypal na?

Comment: I don't know who had upvoted this, 
This is copy & paste answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862059/rbs-worldpay-integration?rq=1

Comment: This is not copy & paste, it was quoted " "! Why should I reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Detail integration of Worldpay you can find it here [Worldpay Android](https://online.worldpay.com/docs/android)